# Implementing ArUco Marker-Based Global Frame for Precise Docking with Nav2 Controller Server

Tags: localization, nav2

I am trying achieve precise docking using ArUco markers, I already have the pose of the marker with respect to my camera? I'm looking to replace the conventional "map => odom" transformation, typically used with AMCL, with the ArUco marker as my new global frame and odometer as my local frame. My goal is to utilize the Nav2 controller server for accurate navigation to my docking station. Do you have any suggestions or guidance on how to implement this transformation effectively?

Comment: Are you using Nav2 to get close to the dock?  My other robot uses mechanical assistance (V shaped guide for rear castor wheel) for the final 300 mm.  I played with using the ArUco markers but gave up for that robot.

New robot - I can't get close enough using odom and Lidar with Nav2 (yet) to use a mechanical guide on this robot.  If you get ArUco "final mile docking" working, I would really like to copy.  At the moment, my robot announces "Assistance wanted with docking, please".